# Can I turn off the modem from inside the computer using any software

Tags: networking, windows-8, modem

Here is the reason I want to do this. Recently when I was configuring my internet connection, after providing all user name and password, the last step was to reboot the modem(not manually, just by clicking the button they have provided on the form).

So if I can reboot a modem from inside the computer like this then I also can turn off the modem right ? Keeping my modem on whole night by forgetting it to turn off manually is causing so many hardware problems now. so does anyone know how can I turn off(or set time to turn it off) the modem from inside the computer using any software? I'm using ITI brand modem. It is mentioned "Type 1 ADSL2+ CPE/ Router" on the box. Model no is DNA-A201BEI. I'm using Windows 8

Comment: Would you care to provide relevant details, such as perhaps the make/model of the modem in question, which OS you're using and so on? Also, do you see any option in the modem's web-based interface that allows you to turn it off? If not, what makes you think such an option exists?

Comment: Hi @Karan, thank you for your quick reply. Sorry for lack of information. I'm using ITI brand modem. It is mentioned "Type 1 ADSL2+ CPE/ Router" on the box. Model no is DNA-A201BEI. I'm using Windows 8 OS.

Comment: @Karan, No there was no option to turn off the modem. After providing appropriate information, There was reboot button. If it won't reboot, then only we will be asked for rebooting it manually. But it does rebooted form me when I clicked that button.

Comment: Is [this](http://bsnl-broadband-solutions.blogspot.com/2012/01/modem-configuration-for-iti-dna-a201bei.html) what you have? Not sure whether it even has a soft power off option. If you can install the Windows Telnet client (or just use PuTTY) and telnet into it, perhaps you'll see a power off option that can then be triggered via a script. (An alternative would be to buy and use a better quality modem if your ISP allows it. I leave my modem/router on 24x7 and no problems yet in all these years.)

Comment: Yeah @Karan, that is what I have. There is save/reboot button on the last snap shot right. So I got this idea.